# Java VM can the heap get smaller?

Tags: java, jvm

if i run a java program the VM initially allocates some memory for the heap, right?

everytime the used memory would take more than available, the heap is increased, right?

is it possible that the heap can get smaller, once less memory is used?

thanks!

Comment: It is worth noting that the JVM allocates the maximum heap size on startup. When the used heap reduces after a GC, it doesn't release memory back to the OS as such. (The only exception I know of is Azul's Zing JVM)

Comment: @PeterLawrey or `G1` since java-12 (under some settings), or `Shenandoah`. times have changed

Comment: @Eugene Even the CMS collector can release memory to the OS in Java 7+, but often doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, garbage collector is free to reduce the size of heap if it discoveres after few collections that the application demand for memory way smaller than configured heap. You can observe this feature in VisualVM, here a Tomcat instance stress tested with [`ab`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html):

[image: VisualVM memory]

As you can see the heap size (orange series) changes basically after every GC (drop in blue series). Sometimes heap size increases, sometimes decreases. JVM is free to adjust the size based on actual usage (here the total heap size was set to 1G).

Comment: As Peter Lawrence mentioned, though the heap size used by the JVM reduces, the actual OS resource does not get released i.e. if you check the process's resident memory, the heap would still be whatever is the max heap used by the JVM so far (with all the Xms, Xmx, heap expansion conditions taken into account)

Answer (score 0):

Well the Java process start with an initial memory allocation for heap and a max alocation for said heap. It's what you pas via the -Xms and Xmx jvm command line arguments. These cannot change during process run.

The actual quantity of memory that is used by your object instances can decrease after a garbage collection.